# Scanf to read this string "[[1,7],[1,3],[7,4],[3,5]]" and construct edge list

Tags: c, graph, scanf

How to use scanf to read this string "[[1,7],[1,3],[7,4],[3,5]]". In the problem description, these are supposed to be edges in a graph: 1-7, 1-3, 7-4, 3-5.

I'm looking for a better way to construct an edge list than reading the string and then looping through every character.

Much thanks

Comment: if your "scanf" is related to 'c' language then please edit and add "c" tag

Answer (score -1):

Try like this,

```
int x[4],y[4];

scanf("[[%d,%d],[%d,%d],[%d,%d],[%d,%d]]",&x[0],&y[0],&x[1],&y[1],&x[2],&y[2],&x[3],&y[3]);
```

Comment: If he doesn't know how many edges there are, this solution isn't better than looping. Instead it only accepts exactly 4 edges, exposing the execution to problems when there are less than 4 edges and ignoring the rest of them if there are more then 4

Comment: @javierdelagarza I don't think so, if your number of edges are dynamic, you have loop for input.